# Setting html in div is skipping first level element in chrome

Tags: jquery

**Edit 1**

This is how I am setting data to div

```
$.ajax({
         url: $('#btn').attr('data-attr-url'),
         type: 'POST',
         data: $form.serialize(),
         success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        // here I am setting data
                        $('#divSurfaceContamination').html(data);

                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(jqXHR.responseText);
                    }
        });
```

---

I am facing an strange issue with Google chrome

I am loading html data in a div like this

```
$('#divData').html(data);
```

where data is the html string that starts with a form element like this

```
<form id="frm"><div id="divDescription" ...
```

This works perfectly on Firefox and IE9 but in IE10 and google chrome it skips the very first element i.e. form in my case and just sets this data to div

```
<div id="divDescription" ...
```

Seems chrome considers `data` as a jquery element and try to set its content only, I am not sure.

However, I have already resolved it by changing the setter like this

```
$('#divData').html("").append(data);
```

and, now it is working in all the browsers.

But I really want to know it is something I was doing wrongly or it is a know thing.

Comment: can u replicate the problem in fiddle ??

Comment: How are you setting 'data'?

Comment: Where is _data_? A URL, file, etc.

Comment: Sounds like you're nesting forms or similar: http://jsfiddle.net/mqK3J/

Comment: @Drewness - It is `data` returned by jquery ajax in success handler. I have added the code in my questiong

Comment: @PawanNogariya - Does `<div id="divSurfaceContamination">` exist before the ajax call?

Comment: @Drewness - Yes, it always stays there, I keep on changing its content when I add or edit any record.

Comment: @TusharGupta - I can't :( It is working correctly in fiddle